SMPS transformer operation and replacement questions
I'm attempting to repair an SMPS for an old iMac. I've traced voltage up to this transformer.

There are 4 leads on the primary side with 1 snipped off. The PCB  has pads for only 3 leads on the primary side. The 2 complete leads on the right are connected, and they are connected to the snipped off one as well. The left-most lead has no continuity to any of the other leads including the snipped off one. The snipped off lead has 2 wires connected to it. Am I correct in assuming that the left-most lead is one of these connections but severed somewhere inside the transformer (and hence no power)? I don't have a great understanding of what this snipped off lead is for so I am guessing here.

is it possible to find a replacement transformer using these part numbers? I haven't bought transformers like this before so don't know if any of these numbers are relevant. It appears to me that finding a matching transformer is like finding a grain of sand on the beach to match the one I have. Lots of them out there but finding the right one is all but impossible.







The unconnected pin is probably an internal shield. It seems to be connected to the optional EMI capacitor C65, a likely common point for a shield.

It is unlikely the transformer was faulty. These are simple devices and are quite robust. The component causing the is most likely elsewhere.

@TimWilliams ah ok I have to look up how an internal shield works and what it is for. Thanks


is it possible to find a replacement transformer using these part numbers?

No. Such transformers are custom-made for a given product. Those are internal part numbers.  They don't mean anything to people other than the product manufacturer. The only place to find another transformer is from another unit of the same product.
